# Windows Phone 8 Scrollview Bouncing back

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, scroll

The Scrollview in my Windows Phone 8 App is working. It scrolls, however when you let go it bounces back to its original state rather then staying at the new state, how would i fix this.

```
            <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="515" Margin="0,253,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Height="619" Width="456">
                    <Button x:Name="Basic_But" Content="basic items" Margin="23,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFBAAFAD" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="413" Click="Basic_But_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Tools_But" Content="tools" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="413" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFBAAFAD" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="89" Click="Tools_But_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Weapons_But" Content="weapons + armour" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,188,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="413" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFBAAFAD" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="89"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Macha_But" Content="machanical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="413" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFBAAFAD" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="89"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Food_But" Content="food" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="413" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFBAAFAD" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="89"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Dyes_But" Content="dyes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,455,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="413" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFBAAFAD" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="89"/>
                    <Button x:Name="About_But" Content="about this app" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,544,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="413" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF5F903F" FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="89"/>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Thanks

Comment: It bounces but you didn't press any button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your scrollviewer is outside of the bound of screen(height). It also happens to me. in your design view see if the scrolviewer is going outside of the visible area. Decrease the height of the scrollviewer so that it is fully appeared in the visible screen.

Hope this helps.